# Box2D strange collisions (jitter) on sharp edges

Tags: box2d, libgdx

I'm currently developing 2D side scroll game with Libgdx + Box2D.
And I'm facing some problems with ChainShape (the ground) and PolygonShape (the cart body) collisions.
Please look at this video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gljgMn8lYfs

As you see the PolygonShape jitters(?) when collides with ChainShape. 
**BUT it only happens on sharp edges!**

What I've tried:

- Increase/decrease velocityIterations/positionIterations. Didin't
  help. Currently they are set to 10/8 (as shown in video).
- Turn off CCD. Didin't help. Currently is turned on.
- Set velocityThreshold to zero. Didin't help. Currently is default - 1f.
- Set restitution/friction values to zero. Didin't help.

Any suggestions why it's happening and how can I fix/avoid it?

Comment: Pretty sure this is a collision detection bug. Please post this up on the Box2D forums for Erin Catto to look at! Be sure to post up the code you use to re-create the exact situation, if possible. The chain shape is a newer type of collider in Box2D.

Comment: RandyGaul thanks again for your idea that ChainShape is a newer type and that's why It can be buggy. I rewrote ground creation script - instead of ChainShape I use PolygonShapes for each segment. The result: http://img534.imageshack.us/img534/8165/oggp.png Physics seems working good now! :)

Comment: Joints have tension. I think what is happening is that when the front wheel is pulling the object into the geometry its stretching the joint which pushes it very hard into the geometry which causes it to bounce off so violently. Try changing the joining location for the front wheel to the front of the cart.

Comment: This definitely look like an amplified unstability due to the geometry of your mesh. the constraint posed by the collision between the main vehicle's rectangle is in conflict with the inertia caused by the wheel's mass. is it possible to disable completely the wheel's mass ?